# Can't get VLookup to work with another Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to place data from one excel file to another, using VBA's VLookup, but without success.

No error is shown and nothing happens. My cells are not being populated although after verification, they should. I cannot debug more than I have, as everything seems to be okay concerning the path, sheet name, and cell rows. I am trying to fetch a value from the source file (SourceFile.xlsx) after a key match on Column B (which contains a unique number).

I have tried the following code with and without the source file being opened, with exact same results:

```
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("B" & cell.Row), Workbooks("C:\Users\halpsb\Desktop\projet_macro\SourceFile.xlsx").Sheets("Projects_2015").Range("B" & cell.Row), 9, False) = "Yes" Then
                .Range("D" & cell.Row) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("B" & cell.Row), Workbooks("C:\Users\halpsb\Desktop\projet_macro\SourceFile.xlsx").Sheets("Projects_2015").Range("B" & cell.Row), 7, False)
            Else
                .Range("D" & cell.Row) = ""
            End If
```

Thank you in advance for any kind of help.

**Edit:** As precised in a comment below, the 7th column is used for my test and contains either "Yes" or "No" strings in the source file. Depending on this value, the 9th column of the source file is used for fetching data and placing it in my original file.

Comment: A quick way to see how to do vlookup in VB, is to just turn on the macro recorder, enter your formula to where you get the result (have your other spreadsheet open too (the `SourceFile.xlsx`). Then, when you have the formula entered, showing the result you want, close your `SourceFile.xlsx` and the formula will update with the filepath.  Post that macro here and we can tweak as necessary.  Also, as mentioned by @HarveyFrench, your vlookup range is a single cell (`Range("B" & cel.row))`...could cause an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your Vlookup formulas contain a "7" and a "9" as they are trying to retrieve data from the 7th and 9th column in the range specified by the second parameter.

BUT, you 2nd parameter only contains one column, which will cause an error

you could add error handlin similar to the example below

```
Sub aa()

On Error Resume Next

Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(2, Sheet1.Range("E4:E10"), 3, False)
if err.number <> 0 then
   Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
   ' an error occurred!
end if    


End Sub
```

Consider this.  The 2nd parameter is a single column!  The 9 is trying to get the 9th column!

```
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(
        .Range("B" & cell.Row)
        , Workbooks("C:\Users\halpsb\Desktop\projet_macro\SourceFile.xlsx").Sheets("Projects_2015").Range("B" & cell.Row)
        , 9
        , False) = "Yes"
```

Comment: The 7 is for the column that contains "Yes" or "No" and the 9 is the value I am actually fetching depending on the Yes/No result, and placing in my original file. Thank you for the error handling part, I was not familiar with this!

Comment: You need to refer the the help pages on vlookup as the parameter are not doing what you think they are.